# Generic implementation that can pass parameter to choose which code to use

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, interface

I have an `interface` like so:

```
public interface IIdentifierManager
{
    Task<bool> Method1(string identifierName, string identifier);
    Task<bool> Method2(IEnumerable<string> ids);
}
```

And five `classes` have implemented it so for example:

```
public class CatIdentifierManager: IIdentifierManager
{
   // you know the dill!
}
```

So when I have:

```
IEnumerable<IIdentifierManager> idManagers;
```

depending on which implementation I want I am doing it like this:

```
 var myVar1 = idManagers.OfType<JoeIdentifierManager>()?.FirstOrDefault();
 var myVar2 = idManagers.OfType<HisIdentifierManager>()?.FirstOrDefault();
 var myVar3 = idManagers.OfType<HerIdentifierManager>()?.FirstOrDefault();
 var myVar4 = idManagers.OfType<CatIdentifierManager>()?.FirstOrDefault();
 var myVar5 = idManagers.OfType<DogIdentifierManager>()?.FirstOrDefault();
```

I am looking for a better design suggestion so maybe I could have one main implementation that has all those five in it and maybe I pass a `parameter` to tell it which one to use.
How do you suggest doing that?

Comment: Any reason you don't just want a `Dictionary<string, IIdentifierManager>` or similar? Just fetch the "right" one from the dictionary based on the key. If that's not appropriate, please clarify the question - at the moment I can't imagine what an answer would look like, because the question isn't specific enough.

Comment: @Bohn: I see that Factory patten is appropriate here like below                              
 `public class IdentifierManagerFactory
{
    public IIdentifierManager GetIdentifierManager(string managerType)
    {
        switch (managerType)
        {
            case "Joe":
                return new JoeIdentifierManager();                                                                       
        } } }`

Comment: Are you using dependency injection?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do anything goofy like one method with a setting parameter to choose an implementation. What you might want is a static factory method that choose an implementation for you, then you can call the method on that.

Don't be afraid to have a couple extra classes or methods so long as they are nice and neat. A lot of developers think that less methods and less classes is better, but in my experience it leads to a mess as the code base grows. You want to change an existing behavior, but it is completely coupled to all the other variants of the function.